# lighttpd and vtiger setup

Tags: postgresql, lighttpd, vtiger, vtigercrm

I am trying to setup vTiger CRM with lighttpd, but I have faced some problems.
I have configured a postgreSQL database devoted to vTiger.
I have downloaded the source and copied that in my /var/www/vtigercrm

when I try to access localhost/vtigercrm, php warns me with some errors like:

```
Warning: include(config.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vtigercrm/config.php on line 21

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'config.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vtigercrm/config.php on line 21

Warning: include_once(include/Webservices/Relation.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vtigercrm/index.php on line 14
```

and warnings go on!

and at last a fatal error destroys everything:

```
 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'include/logging.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vtigercrm/include/database/PearDatabase.php on line 16
```

**IT IS SOLVED**

For others who may have the same problem, it is a good idea to change error displaying settings in `php.ini` file to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE` while you are installing vTiger. Then you can revert the changes.
It is due to the fact that if you send something to browser output, you cannot manipulate the headers anymore; sending output is done by error_display while installation wizard tries to modify some http headers.

Comment: would you please check your file permission and try to access installation page. The first visit must redirect you to installation page anyway. and at first you will not have `config.inc.php` there in your root directory. You can create that manually too

Comment: @webDev thank you, in fact the source i had downloaded was corrupted. Now my problem is that it asks me for mysqli support while I want to integrate vTiger with **postgreSQL**

Comment: put your solution as an answer (comment as answer) so that other can get it as solution.